# UIImage Temporaria

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Eu preciso baixar uma imagem, a mesma é exibida, porém depois de exibi-la preciso excluir ela do dispositivo. Mas sempre quando eu abro o aplicativo novamente ela ja está carregada.

```
func getPhoto(pathPhoto: String, imageview: UIImageView) {

        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, imageview.frame.size.width - 40, imageview.frame.size.height - 40))
        activityIndicator.color = UIColor(red: 64.0/255.0, green: 109.0/255.0, blue: 157.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        imageview.addSubview(activityIndicator)

        var photoUrlString = urlImages

        photoUrlString += pathPhoto

        var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: photoUrlString)!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if data == nil {
                    NSLog("Erro ao baixar")
                } else {
                    self.image = UIImage(data: data)

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        self.activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
                        imageview.image = self.image
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Por favor adicione informações de como você baixa a imagem e como ela é carregada.

Comment: Em nenhum momento no seu código a imagem está sendo salva no dispositivo. Tem certeza que é esse o trecho de código mesmo?

Comment: Exato, por isso que queria saber como excluir a imagem que estava sendo salva temporariamente. Abaixo segue a solução como resposta que encontrei.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A razão é que `NSURLConnection` armazena automaticamente em cache respostas a solicitações HTTP localmente. Então, enquanto você não pode ser salvar a imagem no diretório do aplicativo, o iOS está guardando para eu.

Como você lida com isso depende de por que você está suprimindo a imagem no dispositivo. Se é porque você quer servir uma nova imagem de cada vez, e você tem controle sobre o servidor, pode fazer sentido para corrigir isso aí, definindo os cabeçalhos HTTP adequados para informar os clientes não para armazenar em cache a imagem.

Para resolver este problema eu adicionei o seguinte trecho de código após o download da imagem:

```
NSURLCache().removeCachedResponseForRequest(request)
```

Ficando da seguinte maneira:

```
func getPhoto(pathPhoto: String, imageview: UIImageView) {

        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, imageview.frame.size.width - 40, imageview.frame.size.height - 40))
        activityIndicator.color = UIColor(red: 64.0/255.0, green: 109.0/255.0, blue: 157.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        imageview.addSubview(activityIndicator)

        var photoUrlString = urlImages

        photoUrlString += pathPhoto

        var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: photoUrlString)!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if data == nil {
                    NSLog("Erro ao baixar")
                } else {
                    self.image = UIImage(data: data)

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                            self.activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
                            imageview.image = self.image

                            NSURLCache().removeCachedResponseForRequest(request)
                        })
                }
            }
        })
    }
```